# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:

Tags: android

THis code is crashing in a few devices .

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(dtStart);
            System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long ere = date.getTime() / 1000;
```

Error:

```
System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15-02-2016 08:56 p.m." (at offset 17)
System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this workaround for your problem.

But actually [Shlublu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419719/2956344) is correct.

```
private static void parseTime(String dtStart) {
    String time = dtStart.substring(0, dtStart.length() - 4);
    System.out.println(time);
    String timePick = dtStart.substring(dtStart.length() - 4, dtStart.length());
    System.out.println(timePick);
    if (timePick.equals("p.m.")) {
        time += "PM";
    } else if (timePick.equals("a.m.")) {
        time += "AM";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(time);
        System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long ere = date.getTime() / 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the `a` part of the pattern. 
It should be "PM", not "p.m.", [according to the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
a   am/pm marker    (Text)  PM
```

This is consistent with the error message you received:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "15-02-2016 08:56 p.m." (at offset 17)

Offset 17 (zero-based) corresponds to the "p" of "p.m.".

Answer (score 0):

The part of the date "p.m." is not recognized as an AM/PM specifier in SimpleDateFormat for the English locale.  It should be AM or PM.